# Preserve settings in the file

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating my excel add-in that saves the current file as csv into user-specified folder. I would like my program to ask for the folder path the first time the program is launched and to remember that folder in the future. I am wondering is there any way to preserve the data within the program? I figured that I could write the path into .txt-file but that feels a little hack-like solution and would clutter the addin folder.

Comment: Easiest solution is to store the value in a cell on a hidden sheet in the xlam, keyed with a username if there are multiple users. If you want other WorkBOOKs to be able to read it, store it in the Registry but that is machine specific.

Comment: A tip for asking on Stack Overflow: only one question per Question. You should [edit] your question to remove the part about a Variable and put that in a new question. But FWIW you can declare the variable as a "global" variable - outside a sub, at the top of the code module (right after `Option Explicit`). Then it will be accessible by all subs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the GetSetting and SaveSetting functions in my VB 6 apps.  Rather than cover them in detail, take a look at this excellent web page that illustrates how to use in with Excel

[Excel Tips From John Walkenbach](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/using_the_getsetting_savesetting_functions/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Worksheet, and store the values in cells.  Then in the VBA Editor find the Worksheet in the Project Explorer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and set "Visible" to "2 - xlSheetVeryHidden" in the Properties Pane (<kbd>F4</kbd>) so that it is not readily visible to users.

You can then set/retrieve the data in with code in the format `SheetName.Cells(row,column).Value`, e.g.

```vb
MyPath = Sheet1.Cells(1,2).Value 'Get data from cell B1
Sheet1.Cells(2,2).Value = NewPath 'Set data in cell B2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this. Besides the hidden sheet approach, already described, you can

- Write the information to a `CustomXMLPart`. This is a xml file stored in the workbook's ZIP file where information can be stored.
- For something as short and simple as a file path, you could also use a CustomDocumentProperty